# FreeRADIUS-OpenLDAPでのパスワード有効期限の設定について

Tags: openldap, vpn

VPNの認証サーバーを構築しようとしています。
以下についてご教示頂けないでしょうか。

FreeRADIUSとopenLDAPはyumでインストールしました。

構成：

PC(Windows7)　→　CiscoASAルータ　→　Freeradius(3.0.13)　→　OpenLDAP(2.4.44)

できること：

OpenLDAPで登録したユーザーとパスワードを使用して、PC(Windows7)からのVPN認証はOK

困っていること：

OpenLDAPの ppolicy でパスワードの有効期限(maxPwdage)を設定しているが、
　パスワードの有効期限が切れた状態でもVPN認証ができてしまう。

知りたいこと：

FreeradiusからOpenLDAPへの接続では OpenLDAPの ppolicy は効かない(無視される)？

→ldapsearchコマンドなどでは "password expire" となり、ppolicy が効いていることは確認済み。

ppolicy 以外で、パスワード有効期限切れの際にVPN認証できないようにする方法はありますか？

FreeRADIUSの各設定ファイルの変更点を記載いたします。

```
・/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
    auth = yes 
    auth_badpass = yes
    auth_goodpass = yes

・/etc/raddb/users
    #DEFAULT        Framed-Protocol == PPP
    #       Framed-Protocol = PPP,
    #       Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP

    #DEFAULT        Hint == "CSLIP"
    #       Framed-Protocol = SLIP,
    #       Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP

    #DEFAULT        Hint == "SLIP"
    #       Framed-Protocol = SLIP

    DEFAULT         Auth-Type = LDAP
                    Fall-Through = Yes

・/etc/raddb/dictionary
    VALUE         Auth-Type               LDAP    5

・/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
            ldap

            Auth-Type LDAP {
                    ldap
            }

            ldap

・/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/ldap
            server = 'server01.radius.local'

            port = 389

            identity = 'cn=admin,dc=radius,dc=local'
            password = password

            base_dn = 'dc=radius,dc=local'
```

追加で必要な情報がありましたら取得しますので、言ってください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

バージョンは freeradius-3.0.13, openldap-2.4.44 でしょうか。
radiusd と slapd はどのように連携していますでしょうか？

(A) freeradius の ldap モジュールで slapd に LDAP bind で認証
(B) LDAPユーザーを sssd や nslcd などで OS ユーザーに見せて、radiusd から PAM 認証
(C) slapd から userPassword 属性値を引いて、radiusd で認証

(A) の場合、ldapsearch と同様に ppolicy が効くはずです。
どこかでキャッシュが効いているのかもしれません。
認証の際、radiusd と slapd のログを確認すると毎回アクセスがあるかどうかわかると思います。

(B) の場合も ppolicy が効くはずですが、sssd, nslcd 側でキャッシュしているかもしれません。

(C) の場合、ppolicy は効きません。

Comment: sssdやnslcdを使用していないので、(A)か(C)なのですが、どちらに該当しているのかの確認方法を教えていただくことはできますでしょうか。

Comment: 質問文を編集し、設定内容を記載ください。

Comment: slapdのログを見ると「 conn=1031 op=1 SRCH attr=userPassword radiusControlAttribute radiusRequestAttribute radiusReplyAttribute」と出ているため、やはりuserPassword属性値を引いてしまっているのでしょうか。(A)を実現するために必要な設定を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: 連携方法は (A) ですね。
slapd のログで、SRCH の後に、ユーザーの dn で BIND しているログがあると思います。

まず、パスワードの有効期限が切れた状態で、radtest で認証に失敗することを確認ください。
radtest で認証に成功するのであれば、Fall-Through で LDAP 以外のユーザー情報を見ているか、キャッシュが有効になっている可能性が考えられます。
認証の際の radiusd と slapd のログを確認ください。

radtest で認証に失敗、VPN で認証に成功するのであれば、VPN 側でキャッシュしている可能性が考えられます。

Comment: radtestで何も指定しないかpapを指定した場合認証失敗します。mschapを指定すると成功します。新規で作ったユーザーでパスワード有効期限切れにしてからログインしても同じ状況です。

Comment: mschap の場合、平文のパスワードまたはNT/LMハッシュを、LDAP (またはパスワードファイルなど)から引いてきて、radiusd が認証します。
(C) に似た方式です。
ppolicy は効きません。

Comment: 因みにですが、FreeRADIUSとopenLDAPについての知識が殆ど無いので教えていただきたいのですが、連携方法が(A)というのは、何を見ると判断できるのでしょうか。

Comment: radiusd のログを見るのが確実です。
バックグラウンドではなく、コマンドライン(シェル)から "radiusd -X" でデバッグログを出力させた状態で認証を試みると、「Found Auth-Type = LDAP」や「Found Auth-Type = mschap」と出力されることを確認できると思います。

Comment: Found Auth-Type = LDAP と Found Auth-Type = mschapのときは、LDAP bindしている状態と認識しました。また、後者はLDAP bindでも(C)の用な動作をすることと理解しました。認証は、mschapv2での認証を想定しているのですが、その際に質問に記載の構成でパスワードの有効期限を設定する方法はありますでしょうか。

Comment: anonymous (または管理者 DN で ) bind でユーザーの DN を取得した後、(A) はそのユーザー DN で bind します(ppolicy が効く)が、(C) ではしません。
(C) でパスワード有効期限を設定する方法は思いつきません。
LDAP の属性に、パスワードを変更した日時、有効期限などの値を持たせ、radiusd 側で計算する方法もあるようです(http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2012-February/059160.html)。

Comment: 教えて頂いたリンク先のやり方でradtestでmschapを指定した際にppolicyの設定が効くようになりました。

Comment: パスワードの有効期限切れた後にVPNクライアントでVPNログインした際「パスワードを変更してください」の様なメッセージが表示され、新しいパスワードに変更できるようにすることは可能でしょうか。

Comment: VPNルータは LDAP は参照せず、RADIUS のみと連携するのですよね？
であれば、パスワードの有効期限が切れたかどうかは VPNルータは知り得ないと思います。

Comment: リンク先記載のPassword changes > LocalでPC側でパスワード変更画面が出るようになりました。（参考URL https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/doc/modules/mschap.rst　パスワード更新については、ldappasswdでパスワード更新し、shadowLastchangeをldapmodifyで更新するシェルをexecで実行することにしたところ、うまく行きました。いろいろとご教示頂きありがとうございました。